# Typescript runtime type testing

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have a Typescript class method  (using the DefinitelyTyped JQuery definitions) that I want to look like this:

```
  DoStuff(data: JQuery | string) {
    if (data instanceof JQuery) 
      DoThis()
    else
      DoThat(); 
  }
```

But the `instanceof` line gives the error: `'JQuery' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

What's the right way of doing this? I could obviously use `typeof(data) != "string"` but that feels like cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an [user-defined guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to check if the parameter is a jQuery instance:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

function isJquery(arg: any): arg is JQuery {
  return arg instanceof $; // Notice that this checks against the real jQuery object and not the interface `JQuery`
}

function DoStuff(data: JQuery | string) {
  if (isJquery(data))
    // `data` will be typed as `JQuery` here
    DoThis();
  else
    // `data` will be typed as `string` here
    DoThat();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a custom type guard to determine whether you have jQuery or not.

The example below is too lightweight for production, as other objects may have an append function - you would want to check enough of the duck to make sure it is a duck, not just the beak. It does demonstrate how to use a custom type guard though:

```
function isJquery(obj: JQuery | any): obj is JQuery {
    return typeof (<JQuery>obj).append === 'function';
}

var x: JQuery | string;

if (isJquery(x)) {
    x.append('Something');
} else {
    x.indexOf('blah...');
}
```

Comment: You don't have to assume all objects with an `append` function are jQuery objects. You can do `obj instanceof $`. See my answer.